# Cypress confirmation dialog

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am writing a test case for part of my app which covers application restart.
During the application restart window confirmation dialog appears which has to be accepted in order to restart the app. And now I have a problem simulating this in Cypress, so my question is:

How to perform `OK` button action in the window confirmation dialog in Cypress test?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
cy.on('window:confirm', () => true);
```

Refer: [App Events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#App-Events)

Comment: Actually this is default setting and default beehavior of Cypress, but sometimes it doesn't work