# How to click Accept in window confirm with Cypress

Tags: alert, cypress

I just got this type of Alert and have no idea how to handle it with Cypress

[image: please click here to view my alert]

Basically, I thought that from the documentation, cypress will automatically accept the alert but turned out the cypress window is stuck when alert appeared

I have tried with some solutions that I read online but none of them help. Like this one below

```
    cy.on('window:confirm', str => {
        expect(str).to.eq('do you swear you are a legitimate user and intend to act honestly?')
    })
```

as they said that if this one return true or doesn't return any thing, it would work. But in real situation, it is not.

```
    it('interceptorTrigger', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:9009/?path=/story/loginwithemail--interceptortrigger')
        cy.getIframe('#storybook-preview-iframe')
            .find('button')
            .click()
        cy.on('window:confirm', str => {
            // expect(str).to.eq('do you swear you are a legitimate user and intend to act honestly?')
        })
        cy.wait(2000)
        cy.log('done')
    })
```

Comment: That's not alert, it's confirm: https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Window-Confirm

Comment: have you try to wait a little bit(`cy.wait(2000)`) after you doing `window:confirm` and an other question did no try to confirm without assertion inside?

Comment: I tried to but a bit wait after doing `window:confirm` but it is still stuck @EvgeniiBazhanov. Update my script in description

Comment: Can you try the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768090/cypress-confirmation-dialog)

Answer (score 3):

Try defining your `cy.on('window:confirm',...)` BEFORE you call `click()`

Check out the ["Catalog of Events"](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html) API documentation page
if you scroll down to the [Examples > Window Confirm](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Window-Confirm) it shows how to intercept the call and make assertions on it:

```
// Define
cy.on('window:confirm', (str) => {
  expect(str).to.eq('first confirm')
  // return false to deny
})
// THEN click
cy.get('button').click()
```

ALSO, mind sharing what your `getIframe()` function looks like?